# Java - Is storing the result of select statement in arraylist is good or bad approach?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am just starting to learn with SQL server 2008 in java. So I was wondering if using this approach is a good one or not? I implemented a generic arraylist method which will get the values from the database.

```
public ArrayList<String> get(){
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {

        // Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost; database = Sample; Integratedsecurity = true");
        String  sql = "Select * from products";
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        // Extract all the records to see the updated records
         rs  = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            // Retrieve data by column name in your database
          a.add(rs.getString("ProductName"));

        }
        rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return a;
}
```

Will this one is good or not? Then in displaying it..

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
        String productName = !request.getParameter("productName").isEmpty() ? request.getParameter("productName") : "Empty";
        d.addProduct(productName);
        a = d.get();

        Iterator<String> it = a.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()){%>
            <% String baba = (String)it.next(); %>
            <p>Product:  <%= baba %></p>
        <%} %>
```

I am wondering if there's any good set-up in doing this and much more easy to understand? Any help/suggestions would be appreciate! Thank you.

Comment: Don't use JDBC directly. Use a library that abstracts it.

Comment: @Falmarri More importantly, do not have DB code in JSP

Comment: is 'get()' returning a local variable?

Comment: If you are going to use JDBC directly, use a connection pool. Also, [clean up after yourself](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/clean-up-after-yourself.html).

Comment: The code is working, I just want to ask and wondering if there's another approach that would be much simple. It returns everything based from the sql query.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes! I heard that it is important to clean your resources. But this is just for testing purposes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fine.

The approach works well even when you have larger result set rows. You would then turn each row into an object of some kind and add that to the Array list.

Where it may not work so well is when you can not retrieve all of the rows due to memory constraints but you would still add the ones you want to return to such a collection.

Comment: I'm thinking of using Array list because it said from the api that it grows and shrinks dynamically. So, knowing that table would be changed dynamically it would be good for an array list because it automatically adjusting it size.

Comment: Yes its a good choice as long as the table doesn't hold more data than you have memory in your application. If that is the case you will need to design a solution that returns what you can cope with and then comes back later for more if you need it. I'm just saying it's not a one size fits all thing here.

Comment: Is the limit of ArrayList depending on your memory? What would be the good approach if i'm dealing for example thousands of data?

Comment: Then you get into a whole new realm of solution design about how to manage large volumes of data in your application. I have worked on apps that hold 10s of thousands of rows in memory and work fine. So don't worry too much.

Comment: But for now, as I am starting to adapt from it, is it a somehow good approach to be implemented?

Comment: i would say it is a good **first** approach. An ArrayList is only limited on your memory. As a workaround of 'too less ram' you can use cursors in jdbc to get not the complete data in a single step.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just retrieving simple Strings for a single attribute, what you propose will do the job.  However, you could run into trouble if you want to work with numbers or other data types.  You would also need to iterate over the ResultSet repeatedly to retrieve other attributes.

I use the following:

```
ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>
```

The ArrayList stores a LinkedHashMap for each row in the result set.  The LinkedHashMap maps each attribute name (the String key) to its corresponding value for the row (the Object value).  This gives me an ordered list of the results where I can retrieve each attribute of each row by name.  Using an Object instead of a String allows me to cast the result as required.  I get all of this in one pass.

The following demonstrates how to populate the list:

```
public Collection<String, Object> storeResults(ResultSet resultSet)
{
  LinkedHashMap<String, Object> attValues = null;
  ResultSetMetadata attValuesData = resultSet.getMetaData();
  int attsInRow = attValuesData.getColumnCount();
  ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> qryRslts = new ArrayList<>();

  while (resultSet.next())
  {
    attValues = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    /*
     * Loop through attributes and store values in attValues.
     * NOTE:  Column numbering starts at 1!!!
     */
    for (int attIndex = 1; attIndex <= attsInRow; attIndex++)
      attValues.put(attValuesData.getColumnLabel(attIndex),
                    resultSet.getObject(attIndex));

    qryRslts.add(attValues);
  }

  return qryRslts;
}
```

JDBC is pretty verbose and requires careful resource handling so if you plan to write a lot of software that will talk to databases, consider abstracting out common functionality (such as the above) into its own utility class(es) and package for re-use.  If you don't want to go to that much trouble, do give some consideration to using Hibernate in the longer term.

Comment: I'm still learning java collections. Can't really understand inside the <>

Comment: The stuff inside the <> merely restricts the contents of the Collection.  For example, if you create an ArrayList<String>, you are saying the ArrayList can only contain Strings.  In my example above, I only use 2 types of Collections.  The first is a LinkedHashMap<String, Object>, which is a hash of String keys (the query attribute names) to Object values (the query result values).  The second is an ArrayList of that LinkedHashMap - ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>.  The LinkedHashMap corresponds to a single row in the table while the ArrayList holds all the rows returned by the query.

Answer (score 0):

I did similar stuff in the past for 'easier handling' of the query result. As years went by i turn away from that because it's more code than really needed. Also it makes things more complicate.
In your approach you do not store the type of data returned by the database. It's just 'String'. I also did this in the past - i wouldn't recommend that...
So my advice is: use pure jdbc functionality in first approach. If you understand that and used it for some time take a look at jpa.

Comment: I don't understand yet jdbc.. Can you please elaborate more? I mean, can you help me more to lead me in the right direction.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html

Comment: @redge: bingo, this should explain the stuff

Comment: @user3323654: what do you mean with 'i don't understand yet jdbc'? you already used it in your code... Just read more about it and you're ready to go.

Comment: I mean i'm just starting from scratch hehe still adapting from it. Anyways, thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use hibernate which automatically binds result to some object may be an `ArrayList<SomeBean>`?

Also it would be a good experience and worth learning it if required. A lot of stuff is available online, may be stackoverflow is itself sufficient.

Comment: he asked for 'an approach that would be much simple'. I think hibernate is not really simple.

Comment: Also a lot of google `Guava` Apies are available to map and fill beans/list from a given resultset, this would be one of the alternate if using hibernate is an over kill for your system.

Comment: Getters and setters methods?

Comment: that is why I am suggesting other common bean utils which may fill beans and make it available for use, if hibernate is not considered. <b>user3323654</B> how is our discussion?

Comment: yes it automatically call them `getters & setters`

Comment: I can't understand clearly the ArrayList<SomeBean> then using an iterator to display it right?

Comment: hey checkout this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741842/how-to-build-this-java-collection-from-a-resultset

Comment: Thanks can you vote my answer up or accept it.